# JSON IOS detailview

Tags: ios, json, detailview

I have a code which downloads a JSON file from a website, and displays it in a table view.
My next step is to show the title (persons name) in the detaillist.

How can i achieve this?
I cannot get into the data that shows on the main screen.

This is the code that shows a name at the first screen.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    // Get the location to be shown
    Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

// Get references to labels of cell
myCell.textLabel.text = item.Name;

    return myCell;
}
```

--- START EDIT-----

I got an NSDictionary in HomeModel.M class.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
    Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
    newLocation.Name = jsonElement[@"Email"];
    newLocation.list = jsonElement[@"lijst"];
    newLocation.Password = jsonElement[@"Password"];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:newLocation];
}

// Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
if (self.delegate)
{
    [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
}
```

--- END EDIT----

So basically what i want is 
in the ToGetList class to show the same name...

something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.nameLabel.text = item.Name //Reference to the ViewController.m class;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to display the selected cell data on the self.nameLabel?

Comment: What you want to do is create an NSDictionary and find the "keywords" within the JSON request. Then set the text of the myCell.textLabel.text to the dictionary with that keyword...

Comment: @サンディープ. yes that is exactly what i want to do.But in addition i want to show details of the selected cell, for example if i select John Doe, i get in the detailview, name = John Doe, Occupation = Shoplifter., when i select Mary Doe, i get name = Mary Doe, occupation = Housewife.

Comment: @user2277872, i have a NSDictionary in my HomeModel.m Class. Which gets all of the data.

Comment: Create a model containing cell components name,Occupation etc...

Answer (score 0):

Create a model containing cell components like name,Occupation etc.
Store all the data from JSON in array.
In

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method

```
self.timeSheetModel = [self.timeSheetListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

self.detailVC = [[DetailVC alloc]init];

//Create a property model in your detailVC assign it.

self.detailVC.model = [self.timeSheetListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Pass the model . You will get the data in your detailVC of the selected cell.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailVC animated:YES];

}
```

In your detailVC you can access the values directly

```
self.myNameLabel.text  = self.model.name;
```